# SQL Query: How to use sub-query or AVG function to find number of days between a new entry?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a two tables, one called `entities` with these relevant columns:
`id`, `company_id` ,and `integration_id`. The other table is `transactions` with columns `id`, `entity_id` and `created_at`. The foreign keys linking the two tables are `integration_id` and `entity_id`.

The `transactions` table shows the number of transactions received from each company from the `entities` table.

Ultimately, I want to find date range with highest volume of transactions occurring and then from that range find the average number of days between transaction for each company.

To find the date range I used this query.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, '%Y/%m/%d'), COUNT(t.id)
FROM entities e
JOIN transactions t
ON ei.id = t.entity_id
GROUP BY t.created_at;
```

I get this:

```
Date_FORMAT(t.created_at, '%Y/%m/%d') | COUNT(t.id)
+-------------------------------------+------------
2015/11/09                             4
```

etc

From that I determine the range I want to use as 2015/11/09 to 2015/12/27
and I made this query

```
SELECT company_id, COUNT(t.id)
FROM entities e
INNER JOIN transactions t
ON e.integration_id = t.entity_id
WHERE tp.created_at BETWEEN '2015/11/09' AND '2015/12/27'
GROUP BY company_id;
```

I get this:

```
company_id  | COUNT(t.id)
+-----------+------------
1234          17
```

and so on

Which gives me the total transactions made by each company over this date range. What's the best way now to query for the average number of days between transactions by company? How can I sub-query or is there a way to use the `AVG` function on dates in a `WHERE` clause?

EDIT:

playing around with the query, I'm wondering if there is a way I can

`SELECT company_id, (49 / COUNT(t.id))`...

49, because that is the number of days in that date range, in order to get the average number of days between transactions?

I think this might be it, does that make sense?

Comment: How did you determine 2015/12/27 as the end of the range you want?

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench to do these queries so I just excerpted a fraction of the query result because I don't know how to copy and paste from Workbench, but when i sorted the `COUNT(t.id)` column, 2015/12/27 is the last day with a transaction count of 2 before it winnows down to 1. So I chose the dates with the highest number of transactions and the most recent date with transactions before they taper off.

Comment: may be help this column ..  avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, time_from, time_to)) AS average_hours?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work:

```
Select z.company_id, 
datediff(max(y.created_at),min(created_at))/count(y.id) as avg_days_between_orders,
max(y.created_at) as latest_order,
min(created_at) as earliest_order, 
count(y.id) as orders
From
(SELECT entity_id, max(t.created_at) latest, min(t.created_at) earliest
FROM   entities e, transactions t
Where  e.id = t.entity_id
group by entity_id
order by COUNT(t.id) desc
limit 1) x,
transactions y,
entities z
where z.id = x.entity_id
and z.integration_id = y.entity_id
and y.created_at between x.earliest and x.latest
group by company_id;
```

It's tough without the data.  There's a possibility that I have reference to integration_id incorrect in the subquery/join on the outer query.